# Hangman reading input file from user

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I am trying to do is to read a **text file from a user** and then run the game with that particular file. I know that it will be more easier to have functions but I don't know how to modify the whole code with functions.

How can I run the game with that text file inputted by user?

```
import random
import sys

choice = None

while choice != "0":
print('''
--------------------
Welcome to Hangman
--------------------

Please select a menu option:

0 - Exit
1 - Enter a new text file to be read:
2 - Play Game

''')
choice= input("Enter you choice: ")

if choice == "0":
    sys.exit("Exiting from Python")
elif choice =="1":
    newIn = []
    fileInput = input("Enter a new text file name: ")
    newIn = open(fileInput).readlines()
    newIn=List

elif choice == "2":
    List = open("words_for_hangman.txt").readlines()
    print('''

Now select your difficulty level:

0 - EASY
1 - INTERMEDIATE
2 - HARD

''')
    level= input("Enter your choice: ")
    if level == "0":
        word = random.choice(List)
        word = word.strip()
        hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
        lives = 10
        guessed = []
    elif level == "1":
        word = random.choice(List)
        word = word.strip()
        hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
        lives = 7
        guessed = []
    elif level == "2":
        word = random.choice(List)
        word = word.strip()
        hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
        lives = 5
        guessed = []

    while lives != 0 and hidden_word != word:
        print("\n-------------------------------")
        print("The word is")
        print(hidden_word.replace("_"," _ "))
        print("\nThere are", len(word), "letters in this word")
        print("So far the letters you have guessed are: ")
        print(' '.join(guessed))
        print("\n You have", lives,"lives remaining")
        guess = input("\n Guess a letter: \n")
        guess = guess.upper()
        if len(guess) > 1:
            guess = input("\n You can only guess one letter at a time!\n Try again: ")
            guess = guess.upper()
        elif guess== " ":
            guess = input("\n You need to input a letter, not a space!\n Come on let's try again: ")
            guess = guess.upper()
        while guess in guessed:
            print("\n You have already guessed that letter!")
            guess = input("\n Please take another guess: ")
            guess = guess.upper()
        guessed.append(guess)
        if guess in word:
            print('''-------------------------------
            ''')
            print("Well done!", guess.upper(),"is in the word")
            word_so_far = ""
            for i in range (len(word)):
                if guess == str(word[i]):
                    word_so_far += guess
                else:
                    word_so_far += hidden_word[i]
            hidden_word = word_so_far
        else:
            print('''-------------------------------
            ''')
            print("Sorry, but", guess, "is not in the word")
            lives -= 1

    if lives == 0:
            print("GAME OVER! You have no lives left")
    else:
        print("\n CONGRATULATIONS! You have guessed the word")
        print("The word was", word)
        print("\nThank you for playing Hangman")
else:
    choice = print("\n That is not a valid option! Please try again!")
    choice = input("Choice: ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first sight, there are two mistakes in the program

1. The lines

   `newIn = open(fileInput).readlines()
   newIn=List`

   first read the file into the variable `newIn` and then remove the content of `newIn` by setting it to the content of `List`. I guess you wanted to do
   `List = open(fileInput).readlines()`
   as you did in the second part.
2. The second mistake is that the whole game is played only when the user presses `2`. Try moving the whole block beginning with

   `while lives != 0 and hidden_word != word:`

   to the left, so that block is entered either when the user presses `1` or `2`. Also, if you do this, the `else` at the end of the program should go right before the `while lives != 0...`

Answer (score 0):

First keep all your files in a folder and run this file..

For choice 1: Give your new.txt file or try with same file of option two.(words_for_hangman.txt)  but it will be easy for your if you keep all your files in same folder.

```
import random
import sys

choice = None

while choice != "0":
    print('''
    --------------------
    Welcome to Hangman
    --------------------

    Please select a menu option:

    0 - Exit
    1 - Enter a new text file to be read:
    2 - Play Game

    ''')
    choice= input("Enter you choice: ")

    if choice == "0":
        sys.exit("Exiting from Python")
    elif choice =="1":
        newIn = []
        fileInput = input("Enter a new text file name: ")
        newIn = open(fileInput).readlines()
        newIn=List

    elif choice == "2":
        List = open("words_for_hangman.txt").readlines()
        print('''

        Now select your difficulty level:

        0 - EASY
        1 - INTERMEDIATE
        2 - HARD

        ''')
        level= input("Enter your choice: ")
        if level == "0":
            word = random.choice(List)
            word = word.strip()
            hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
            lives = 10
            guessed = []
        elif level == "1":
            word = random.choice(List)
            word = word.strip()
            hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
            lives = 7
            guessed = []
        elif level == "2":
            word = random.choice(List)
            word = word.strip()
            hidden_word = "*" * len(word)
            lives = 5
            guessed = []

        while lives != 0 and hidden_word != word:
            print("\n-------------------------------")
            print("The word is")
            print(hidden_word.replace("_"," _ "))
            print("\nThere are", len(word), "letters in this word")
            print("So far the letters you have guessed are: ")
            print(' '.join(guessed))
            print("\n You have", lives,"lives remaining")
            guess = input("\n Guess a letter: \n")
            guess = guess.upper()
            if len(guess) > 1:
                guess = input("\n You can only guess one letter at a time!\n Try again: ")
                guess = guess.upper()
            elif guess== " ":
                guess = input("\n You need to input a letter, not a space!\n Come on let's try again: ")
                guess = guess.upper()
            while guess in guessed:
                print("\n You have already guessed that letter!")
                guess = input("\n Please take another guess: ")
                guess = guess.upper()
            guessed.append(guess)
            if guess in word:
                print('''-------------------------------
                ''')
                print("Well done!", guess.upper(),"is in the word")
                word_so_far = ""
                for i in range (len(word)):
                    if guess == str(word[i]):
                        word_so_far += guess
                    else:
                        word_so_far += hidden_word[i]
                hidden_word = word_so_far
            else:
                print('''-------------------------------
                ''')
                print("Sorry, but", guess, "is not in the word")
                lives -= 1

        if lives == 0:
                print("GAME OVER! You have no lives left")
        else:
            print("\n CONGRATULATIONS! You have guessed the word")
            print("The word was", word)
            print("\nThank you for playing Hangman")
    else:
        choice = print("\n That is not a valid option! Please try again!")
        choice = input("Choice: ")
```

Comment: Sorry for not understanding but I followed your advice, it run with my text file "words_for_hangman", but with my new new.txt file it's not working. I saw that I write "newIn=List" and List it's not defined yet. I should do there any modifications?

Comment: @JohnRoberts Yeah I have just tried to run this by choose2 , but didn't went in details of your program. Anyway you got the solution.Keep Coding. Good Day